# Access app singleton instance in wsgi application

Tags: python, flask, celery, wsgi, gunicorn

I would like to define some celery tasks. This is my `tasks.py` module:

```
from celery import Celery


def create_celery_app(app):
    celery = Celery(__name__, broker=app.config['CELERY_BROKER_URL'])
    celery.conf.update(app.config)
    TaskBase = celery.Task

    class ContextTask(TaskBase):
        abstract = True

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            with app.app_context():
                return TaskBase.__call__(self, *args, **kwargs)

    celery.Task = ContextTask
    return celery


celery = create_celery_app(app)  # <--- How to access app here?

@celery.task()
def add_together(a, b):
    return a + b
```

The problem is, I have no access to the `app` here! My app is defined in my `wsgi.py` module (I am serving with `gunicorn`)

```
from myproj.app import create_app

app = create_app()
```

With `app.py` being:

```
...

def create_app():
    """
    app = Flask(__name__)
    ...
    return app
```

How can I access the `app` singleton instance, created in the `wsgi.py` module, from my `tasks.py`?

Comment: `from wgsi import app` ... `celery = create_celery_app(app)`

Comment: @KylePittman: does not work, creates circular import

Comment: Why not just call `create_app`?

Comment: @dirn: app is already created by the wsgi middleware, and besides, importing create_app causes a circular import

Comment: You should be able to refactor your application to avoid a circular import.

Comment: What about `from flask import current_app as app`

Comment: @goodcow: no current_app during declaration time ...

Comment: @Monkey: don't know how to achieve that. There seems to be a real circular dependency: the flask views (part of the flask application) need celery tasks, and the celery worker (running the tasks, in a separate process), need the flask application. I have seen simple implementations where the Flask application and the celery tasks are defined in the same module (`app.py`), so both the flask application and the celery worker can be run from the same file (no need to import anything), but in my case wsgi.py defines the application, so I need to import it, causing circular dependency.

Comment: But even in those simple cases, I do not know how the dependency flask <-> celery worker is solved at the process level. I would say the celery worker instantiates a new flask application, different than the one used to serve the requests, and uses that to access the flask objects. That to me seems very brittle, since it is difficult to guarantee that the "fake" flask application instance used by the worker follows the exact same configuration path than the real flask application serving the requests.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I use an app-factory in Flask / WSGI servers and why might it be unsafe?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751277/how-can-i-use-an-app-factory-in-flask-wsgi-servers-and-why-might-it-be-unsafe)