# Flask-Script loads app before running unittests

Tags: python, flask, python-unittest, flask-script

I'm using `Flask-Script` to run tests on my application the important bit of my `manage.py` file looks like this:

```
import unittest

from flask.ext.script import Manager
from project import app

manager = Manager(app)

@manager.command
def test():
    """Run unit tests."""
    app.config.from_object('config.Test')
    tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests', pattern='*.py')
    unittest.TextTestRunner(verbosity=1).run(tests)
```

But when I run `python manage.py test` it tries to initialise the entire application so if, for example, I haven't set my environment variables it throws a `KeyError` from my project's `__init__.py` file like so:

`File "project/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    app.config.from_object(os.environ['PROJECT_SETTINGS'])`

Or if I have set the environment variable I get an error about missing database tables.

Surely the app should only initialise once the tests are running and the configuration variables have been set in the `test()` function.

Comment: You import `app` at the top of the module. Anything inside `project/__init__.py` is going to run when you do that.

Comment: Thanks @dim. The problem is `Manager` requires it so I don't see how I can get around that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you need to do to get this to work.

1. Set the missing environmental variables (like you already said).
2. Create a test database for your tests to use and have your tests include a `setup` and a `teardown` function that create the tables and remove them respectively.

To get around step one I suggest using the [Flask application factory pattern](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appfactories/) which allows you to encapsulate your application creation inside a function. This will allow you to pass in whatever variables, etc are necessary to run your application under a test environment i.e.

```
def create_application(is_test=False):
    app = Flask(__name__)
    if not is_test:
       setup_app_not_for_test(app)
    else:
       setup_test_for_app(app)

    return app
```

In regards to step number 2, if you are using pytest or nose or any sort of testing framework that uses fixtures you can easily add `setup` and `teardown` functions to add/drop database tables. Additionally, if you are using an ORM like sqlalchemy you can create an [SQLite in memory database](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/core/engines.html#sqlite) very easily to run your tests against.

```
# create db instance
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite://:memory:"

# create all your tables
db.create_all()

# drop all your tables
db.drop_all()
```

Comment: Nice one @pech0rin - I'm going to have to refactor this app a bit and do away with Flask-Script but I can see how it all works now. Thanks to your answer I also found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751277/how-can-i-use-an-app-factory-in-flask-wsgi-servers-and-why-might-it-be-unsafe#13754387)